# maven-frontend-plugin use system node

Tags: node.js, maven, plugins, gulp

Its posibble to just execute gulp,grunt,npm,bower task without install node and npm through the plugin using the node and npm installed in the system?

```
  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
            <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- NB! Set <version> to the latest released version of frontend-maven-plugin, like in README.md -->
            <version>@project.version@</version>

            <executions>

                <!-- <execution>
                    <id>install node and npm</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nodeVersion>v0.12.2</nodeVersion>
                        <npmVersion>2.7.6</npmVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>-->

                <execution>
                    <id>grunt build</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>grunt</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <arguments>--no-color</arguments>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>

            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like it, according to the author's comments on this issue :

https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin/issues/277

Maven-exec-plugin may have what you need.

Comment: From how to ask a question: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline."